# How to get SUM for all of column with JS

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I'm wondering how to get the sum of the columns in tables on change dropdown every time number of column changing.

I Already have a code which is calculate the sum indeed but I already have a calculated total when I'm changing the number of some of column it calculate from the first I wanted to complete the calculation.

I hope you guys getting me well.

And here is a picture to explain my point:

[image: Click here to see the image]

Here is my code:

```js
let amount = 0;
$(".total").each(function() {
  amount += parseFloat($(this).val());
});
document.getElementById('gross_amount').innerHTML = amount;
```

Comment: Add an _input_ event listener to the fields and run your code in that

Comment: Sorry bro but I don't getting you exactly can you tell how to do it exactly